# WPF TypeConversionAttribute for collection DP

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have an ObservableCollection as a dependency property(say Points) in a custom control.

I want to initialize it like this

```
<MyControl Points="1,1, 2,2"/>
```

How do I go about defining and creating a typeconverter for the specific DP?

I know there is a specialized points collection class with a built in typeconverter but I cannot use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a `TypeConverter` on the CLR property wrapper for your dependency property. Like this:

```
public class MyControl : Control 
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyStringToPointCollectionConverter))]
    public ObservableCollection<Point> Points {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Point>)GetValue(Points yProperty); }
        set { SetValue(Points Property, value); }
    }
    ...
}
```

And the converter would look something like this:

```
public class MyStringToPointCollectionConverter : TypeConverter {
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value) {
        var stringValue = value as string;

        if (stringValue != null) {
            var result = new ObservableCollection<Point>();

            // Here goes the logic of converting the given string to the list of points

            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great. But it doesn't seem to work for the VS designer. Any thoughts?

Comment: @NVM - No, sorry. Don't know how VS designer works. But you might want to use a Reflector to see how this is implemented, for example, for the Data property of the Path object.

Answer (score 0):

good question. There's a way to do that - change DP for your Points to be of object/string type (to avoid invalid cast exception) and do conversion within a DP change event handler. In the end you've got little to lose - DP system isn't exactly a type safe framework.

That will work. I can quite see JSON as a format for your serialized data.

Another approach would be to introduce a higher level of abstraction on top of your observable collection. Typically that eases the pressure on XAML.

Comment: [TypeConverter(typeof(*))] is by all means slicker.